# UICollectionView within UITableViewCell with Swipe

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I am using Xcode 7.1 and Swift 2.1 version.
I am looking for something as shown in the picture
[image]

Here in the left screen **(Before Swiping)**, I have a `UITableView` in which there are certain cells in which I have to implement a right swipe functionality.
Now when I swipe right the one coming from right must be a `UICollectionView` as shown in right picture **(After Swipe)** as there can be many options (a,b,c,d,e....). So they should be in some scroll view like `UICollectionView`.
I searched a lot and found some libraries like

https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell
https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell
They provide array of `UIButton` or a single Button with image or text. We can add multiple buttons but they will shrink accordingly.

I want something called a `UIView` in which I can place `UICollectionView` and make its datasource accordingly with fixed size cells as shown in the picture.
Any source or link for the same is highly appreciable.
Thanks

Comment: Please do tell the reason too if you voted for closing?
Thanks

Comment: Its a good question... who voted for closing ?